# Is bitwiseAnd operation is cheaper than the type cast to <int>?

Tags: c++, cuda

I am following the [`2_Concepts_and_Techniques/particles`](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-samples/blob/e612904184446c81e4d5beac8755081f9662cca0/Samples/2_Concepts_and_Techniques/particles/particles_kernel_impl.cuh#L107-L124) CUDA sample, and I encountered these lines of code:

```
// calculate position in uniform grid
__device__ int3 calcGridPos(float3 p) {
  int3 gridPos;
  gridPos.x = floorf((p.x - params.worldOrigin.x) / params.cellSize.x);
  gridPos.y = floorf((p.y - params.worldOrigin.y) / params.cellSize.y);
  gridPos.z = floorf((p.z - params.worldOrigin.z) / params.cellSize.z);
  return gridPos;
}

// calculate address in grid from position (clamping to edges)
__device__ uint calcGridHash(int3 gridPos) {
  gridPos.x = gridPos.x &
              (params.gridSize.x - 1);  // wrap grid, assumes size is power of 2
  gridPos.y = gridPos.y & (params.gridSize.y - 1);
  gridPos.z = gridPos.z & (params.gridSize.z - 1);
  return __umul24(__umul24(gridPos.z, params.gridSize.y), params.gridSize.x) +
         __umul24(gridPos.y, params.gridSize.x) + gridPos.x;
}
```

The first suspicious part of this code is that it stores `float floorf(float)` to `uint3 gridPos`. I think it is highly unlikely that this more or less 'official' sample code contains such an error, and I expect this is on purpose, which is related to the very next function.

In the second function, it uses bitwiseAnd `&` operation. As can be seen from its comment, the grid size is assumed to be power of 2. Therefore, `gridPos.x & (params.gridSize.x - 1)` should be more or less the same as `gridPos.x`. The only reason for this operation I can think of is that it is trying to cast `float` to `int` in more efficient way (see how this code is eager to be efficient - it uses `__umul24` for multiplication).

Therefore, I think this code is written in this way because it tries to work-around expensive type cast. Is my interpretation right?

If I am willing to sacrifice such a technical optimization for readability, would it be safe to replace those lines into

```
// calculate address in grid from position (clamping to edges)
__device__ uint calcGridHash(int3 gridPos) {
  gridPos.x = (int)gridPos.x
  gridPos.y = (int)gridPos.y;
  gridPos.z = (int)gridPos.z;
  return (gridPos.z * params.gridSize.y) * params.gridSize.x) +
         (gridPos.y * params.gridSize.x) + gridPos.x;
}
```

Comment: Whenever you feel the need to do a C-style casting in a C++ program, you should take that as a sign that you're probably doing something wrong. But that, as `static_cast` (which you should use instead) and `reinterpret_cast` are compile-time operations. There's no runtime code generated for such conversions.

Comment: Also, shouldn't all parts of an `int3` already *be* `int` values? So the cast and the assignments really make no sense.

Comment: this would cast to int automatically and then do the bitwise-and. It's not saving anything.

Comment: If the only thing that ever happens is that you call `calcGridPos` and then you call `calcGridHash` on the result, then your adaptation might be OK.  But the `calcGridHash` code is designed to take a position that is potentially out-of-range, and make it in-range, according to a kind of modulo formula.  So if  `calcGridHash` is used elsewhere in the code that you are working on, then it would be very important to do range analysis on all other usages.  If it were me, and I were working on a large code base or reusable library, I wouldn't make that change you propose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are missing a few things in the code you posted.

In `calcGridPos` a floating point position is translated to an integer grid position. For example, if you have a particle with the position 29.5 and you try to place that on a grid with cell size 3.3 that has its origin at 5.8. Then the calculation is:

```
(29.5 - 5.8) / 3.3 = 7,18
floor(7.18) = 7
```

So, your particle is in grid cell 7. This is an integer by design because it makes no sense to talk about fractional cells (if you wanted smaller ones, then you should just change the cell size).

So while the line `gridPos.x = floorf((p.x - params.worldOrigin.x) / params.cellSize.x);` converts a float to an integer it loses no information. See also [the documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/group__CUDA__MATH__SINGLE.html#group__CUDA__MATH__SINGLE_1gdbff62f4c1647b9694f35d053eff5288) which says:

> float floorf ( float  x ) : Calculate the largest integer less than or equal to x.

Then in `calcGridHash` they use the bitwise operation to ensure that whatever grid position you show up with lands inside the grid they are currently operating on. So if they are on a 64x64 grid and you hand them a position of (77,258), then they are going to wrap your position until it is in range:

```
77 mod 64 = 13
258 mod 64 = 2
```

Then calculate the hash from the position (13,2).

Modulo operations are traditionally slow. However, it just so happens that if the grid size is a power of 2, then the binary representation of it has only a single bit set and `grid size - 1` will turn off that single bit and set all lower bits. Then you can do the modulo operation by doing a bitwise-and with that.

Of course, if your grid size is set at compile time, then the compiler itself can translate the more readable `x % size` into the bitwise operation. But if the grid size is set at runtime, then the compiler has no chance and you have to do this optimization yourself (hopefully with appropriate checks that your grid size is indeed set to a power of 2).

Your proposed version has none of this wrap-around functionality at all. In fact `gridPos.y = (int)gridPos.y;` does nothing at all since `gridPos.y` is already an `int`.

Comment: Re: "`gridPos.x = floorf((p.x - params.worldOrigin.x) / params.cellSize.x);` **casts** a float to an integer" (emphasis added) -- there are no casts in that line of code. The code **converts** a `float` to an integer. A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer, it helped a lot in understanding the sample code. I want to add one more point for future newbies just like me. BitwiseAnd `&` with power of 2 is turned out to be "not" equivalent to `mod` with (power of 2 - 1). They behave differently with negative numbers. For example, `-1 % 8 = -1`, while `-1 & 7 = 7`.